# Implementing the correct NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs to a List member

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am currently creating a `UserControl`, named `DecoratedComboBox`. It is a control with a styled `ComboBox` and some buttons nearby for implementing some logic.

`DecoratedComboBox` has a custom `ItemsSource` (of type `List`) and several other parameters in order to show within the `ComboBox` this field or that field from the items in the `ItemsSource`. The `ItemsSource`of the `ComboBox` is bound to the field `ItemsToShow` (of type `List`) and I would like to synchronize both lists so that the items in `ItemsToShow` reflect the ones in `ItemsSource`.

Currently, I am working on the mechanism of the event `ItemsSource_CollectionChanged` within this piece of code:

```
    public IList ItemsToShow
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsToShowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsToShowProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsToShowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(DecoratedComboBox),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                    null,
                                                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
                                                  )
                                    );

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(DecoratedComboBox),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                    null,
                                                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                                    new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback)
                                                  )
                                    );
    private static void ItemsSourcePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject sender_decorated_combobox, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs items_source_changed_args)
    {
        DecoratedComboBox decorated_combobox = sender_decorated_combobox as DecoratedComboBox;
        if decorated_combobox != null)
        {
            decorated_combobox.ItemsSourceChanged(items_source_changed_args.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged,
                                                  items_source_changed_args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged);
            decorated_combobox.BuildList();
        }
    }
    private void ItemsSourceChanged(INotifyCollectionChanged old_value, INotifyCollectionChanged new_value)
    {
        if (old_value != null) { old_value.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ItemsSource_CollectionChanged); }
        if (new_value != null) { new_value.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ItemsSource_CollectionChanged); }
    }
    private void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender_items_source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        //Insert the items corresponding to args.NewItems at args.NewStartingIndex
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
        //What to put here?
        //Should I use only args.OldStartingIndex, args.NewStartingIndex?
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        //Remove all the items corresponding to args.OldItems
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        //What to put here?
        //Should I use only args.OldItems, args.NewItems, args.NewStartingIndex?
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        BuildList();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
private void BuildList()
{
    //Fully build (again) ItemsToShow
}
```

Before implementing my own logic, I would like to know which lines of code to put instead of the "What to put here?" comments in order to make `ItemsToShow` reflect `ItemsSource`?

I read ([on this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html)) about which members of `args` are of use depending on the case, but I haven't double-checked yet, thus the interrogation marks.

The key idea here is that this (rather long) piece of code would become a pattern to apply wherever I need to add an `ItemsSource` to any control that I am conceiving.

Thanks in advance for any clue, I can provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen out for these events without having to worry about implementing a brand new `ItemsSource` property. Instead, you can simply use the existing `ItemsSource` property.

If I were you, I'd simply call `BuildList` every time there is a change. See the following example:

```
public class DecoratedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public IList ItemsToShow
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsToShowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsToShowProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsToShow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsToShowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsToShow", typeof(IList), typeof(DecoratedComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    static DecoratedComboBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DecoratedComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DecoratedComboBox)));
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);

        BuildList();
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        BuildList();
    }

    private void BuildList()
    {
        //Clear the ItemsToShow List
        ItemsToShow.Clear();

        //TODO: Work out what to put in ItemsToShow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the trouble is that I would like to build the inner `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` from two parameters : my `DecoratedComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` and a custom `DecoratedComboBox`'s `String` property named `TextPath`. Because the `ItemTemplate`-ing of the `ComboBoxItem` is based on `Binding` and I can't bind to `TextPath` the `Path` property of this `Binding`. Furthermore, I would like to understand how `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` is parametrized by the WPF framework. :)